# App Store Updates staying in queue after installation?

Tags: mac-appstore

There definitely seems to be a bug here. I just installed these, possibly already more than once, but they're still "Available":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally restarting should fix that.

This could a problem of broken permissions that can be repaired in disk Utility.

If above did not work:

It also sounds like your problems are being caused by corrupted preference files. Located in ~/Library/Preferences/

```
com.apple.storeagent.plist
com.apple.appstore.plist
```

Quit all applications on your Mac, delete the two files above, and reboot your Mac.

Comment: Thanks, but neither solution had any effect

Comment: But, allowing the app to 'update all' one further time _has_ now succeeded...